# D3 Selecting based on text value of node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Say I have an svg:

```
<svg>
  <text font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="63" x="69.5" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">1</text>
  <text font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="194" x="73.5" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">2</text>
  <text font-size="24" id="svg_3" y="313" x="60.5" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">3</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

What argument to `svg.selectAll()` or `svg.filter()` can I use to select only the text node with value "2" and use `.attr()` to change its color?

I have found a lot of literature on selecting by attribute, but not by text value.

Comment: document.getElementById('svg_2').textContent use this code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`text()` without arguments is a *getter*.

Thus, inside the `filter` function, this code:

```
d3.select(this).text() == 2
```

Will be evaluated as `true` for any `<text>` element with "2" as value.

Here is a demo:

```js
d3.selectAll("text")
  .filter(function(){ 
    return d3.select(this).text() == 2
  })
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
    <text font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="20" x="20" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">1</text>
    <text font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="50" x="20" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">2</text>
    <text font-size="24" id="svg_3" y="80" x="20" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">3</text>
</svg>
```

PS: in D3, getters normally return a *string*. That's why I'm not using the strict equality operator (`===`). Check it:

```js
var value = d3.select("#svg_2").text();
console.log("value is: " + value);
console.log("type is: " + typeof(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
    <text font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="20" x="20" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">1</text>
    <text font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="50" x="20" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">2</text>
    <text font-size="24" id="svg_3" y="80" x="20" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">3</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: You could also use `+d3.select(this).text() === 2`, if you want jslint, jshint, eslint, etc. to shut up about "==" vs. "===".

Comment: @JarrettMeyer yes, indeed. I personally never use `==` in production, so you can either use the unary plus or compare the getter with `"2"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  $('#box').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    var noresult = 0;
    if(valThis === ""){
        $('.navList > text').show();
        noresult = 1;
        $('.no-results-found').remove();
    } else {
        $('.navList > text').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var match = text.indexOf(valThis);
            if (match >= 0) {
                $(this).show();
                noresult = 1;
                $('.no-results-found').remove();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });   };

    if (noresult === 0) {
        $(".navList").append('<text font-size="24" id="" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000" class="no-results-found">No results found.</text>');
    } }); });




Add a text box where you can search

<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />



<svg class="navList">
  <text font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="20" x="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">1</text>
  <text font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="40" x="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">2</text>
  <text font-size="24" id="svg_3" y="60" x="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">3</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: I think you are asking for the filter in your **svg** tag

Comment: Just add the above script and the text box and you can do this